# accessing index array from gotmpl

Tags: go, templates, indexing, go-templates, go-swagger

I have this list of an array and want to print `something` if index = 0, but print `something else` after that.
I've looked at [this docs](https://docs.gomplate.ca/syntax/#indexing-arrays-and-maps) but seems not successful... all of them is printing `something else` instead.

```
  {{ range $i, $v := .Lists }}
    {{ if $i = 0 -}}
      do something
    {{- else -}}
      do something else
    {{- end -}}
  {{- end }}
```

Comment: It's `{{ if eq $i 0 }}`. Go templates do not have support for standard binary comparison operators, you need to use functions, `eq` is a builtin function that does equality comparison.

Comment: At the top of the linked gotmpl documentation it says: *"Gomplate uses the syntax understood by the Go language’s text/template package."* The documentation of which is [here](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) and for the section on functions, scroll [here](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#hdr-Functions).

Comment: wow, it works with function `eq`.
@mkopriva thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try `==` not `=`.
maybe like this

```golang
 {{ if $i == 0 -}}
```

in documment:

###### And the following comparison operators are also supported:       `eq: Equal (==)`...

https://docs.gomplate.ca/syntax/#functions

Comment: no, it can't. 
it cant be "0" also.

it was printing 0 though if I print the `$i`

Comment: in doc ```And the following comparison operators are also supported:

    eq: Equal (==)... ``` https://docs.gomplate.ca/syntax/#functions

Comment: yeah, that's why it was wierd. the error was
`could not add template: failed to load template clientClient: template: clientClient:127: unexpected "=" in if`